# How do I manage parenting to an armature with a large number of bones?

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups

I'm making a low-poly model with arms that are a separate object from the actual body. That's fine with me, I'm okay with some of the clipping that occurs, but what I'm not fine with is how long it takes to redo vertex groups for bones, especially if I later decide I want to add a new bone or remove one.

The Mirror X feature means I don't have to worry about mirroring bones on both sides, but if I wanted to edit something on both arms that's bothering me, I have to work on one arm, delete the other arm, duplicate the modified arm, scale it by -1, and move it, then (worst of all) I have to rename a bunch of "L"s to "R"s or vice versa.

I've considered instead trying to split my armature into multiple armatures that are nested in each other, but this messes up poses. This is especially annoying since I was hoping this solution would allow me to make parenting things like hair far easier since I can avoid sorting through eighteen vertex groups to find the four relevant ones.

My main question is, is there a way I can parent objects to my armature and selectively choose which bones get vertex groups without having to manually sort through a long list?